# How to display content from selected WPF ComboBox item C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, xaml

i hope everyone is well I am building a small application in C# and WPF, I am trying to add a functionality where when the combo Box is clicked and a certain element is selected, I want to display the contents of the text, but I[image] cant seem to get it right. I would love some input on how to solve this issue, please take a look at the C# code and if you have a solution to it please post it, thank you, NOTE as you might see from the code, I am a beginner coder. Thanks in advace for the help.

```
namespace WPFDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textToDisplay.IsReadOnly = true;

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Title = "Import new template";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            loadTemplates();
        }

        // Load the templates in the directory
        private void loadTemplates()
        {
            string[] templates = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\injanlee\source\repos\WPFDemo\WPFDemo\Snow Templates");
            Array.Sort(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\injanlee\source\repos\WPFDemo\WPFDemo\Snow Templates"));
            Array.Sort(templates);
            foreach (string template in templates)
            {
                //string fileName = template.Split("\\")[5].Split(".")[0];
                string fName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(template);
                selectOption.Items.Add(fName);
                
            }
            
        }

        private async Task Sleep(int miliSeconds)
        {
            await Task.Delay(miliSeconds);
            myLabel.Content = " ";
        }
        

        private async void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textToDisplay.Text);

            myLabel.Content = "Copied to clipboard";
            myLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
            await Sleep(3000);
        }

        private void DisplayFileContent(string path)
        {
            textToDisplay.Clear();
            try
            {
                string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                foreach (string line in fileContent)
                {
                    textToDisplay.Text += line;
                    textToDisplay.Text += "\n";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Unable to find the path for the specific selected File: {selectOption.Text}");
                
            }
            
            
        }


        // Import and save new file template
        public void importTemplate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            saveFileDialog.Title = "Save To";
            openFileDialog.Title = "Import new template";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {

                
                string[] fileName = openFileDialog.FileName.Split("\\");
                string importedFileName = fileName[5].Split(".")[0];
                saveFileDialog.FileName = importedFileName;
                

                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    string location = saveFileDialog.FileName;
                    File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, location, true);
                }

                selectOption.Items.Add(fileName[5].Split(".")[0]);
                MessageBox.Show("Impor successfull");
                
                
            }
        }


        private void selectOption_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectOption.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                DisplayFileContent(@"C:\Users\injanlee\source\repos\WPFDemo\WPFDemo\Snow Templates\Template.txt");
            }
           
        }


        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: basically when y select an option in the item list I want to display the content of the text, except that i cant get it right, the problem is that i dont know how to get the name of selected item, for example, if I select Deleting browsing template Item, i want to display the contents of that .txt file, now i know how to display it, but i dont know how to get the name of the selected item dynamically

Comment: In general you're doing everything in a wrong (too hard for me) way. Consider to learn something about Data Bindings in WPF and MVVM programming pattern. Also move the startup code from Window constructor to `Window.Loaded` event handler. In short you may use `selectOption.SelectedItem` property to get the contents of the selected item.

Comment: Tip: one-liner to display the text: `textToDisplay.Text = File.ReadAllText(path)`

Comment: Another tip `string importedFileName = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName).Split(".")[0]` but be careful with filenames like `my.file.txt` containing multiple dots.

Comment: @aepot, thank you soooo much, I have been struggling with this for the past week, and it was a simple  SelectOption.selectedItem. I really appreciate your help, also thank you for the tips I just implemented the changes and works awesome. Much appreciated.

I just learned a lot from you, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This question got answered by @aepot:

> In short you may use `selectOption.SelectedItem` property to get the contents of the selected item.